# How can I maintain the order of keys I add to a Perl hash?

Tags: perl, hash

How can I maintain the order of actual list after counting its occurrence using a hash in the following program?  For example, `<DATA>` are

```
a
b
e
a
c 
d 
a
c
d
b
etc.
```

Using hash, i counted the occurrence of each element.

and what i want is:

```
a  3
b  2
e  1
c  2
d  2
```

but the following program shows me otherwise.

```
my (%count, $line, @array_1, @array_2);
while ($line = <DATA>) {
    $count{$line}++ if ( $line =~ /\S/ );
}
@array_1 = keys(%count);
@array_2 = values(%count);
for(my $i=0; $i<$#array_1; $i++)
{
   print "$array_1[$i]\t $array_2[$i]";
}
```

Comment: Can you please tag your code, to read it easily.

Comment: @Sinan: No... its not that...... i couldnot find the place to acknowledge all wonderful answers.... just wondering either it is done by adding a comment or is there other place..... a newbie to stackoverflow as well as perl... 
Sorry, May be i should take some time to learn how to take part actively in this platform...
Almost all the answers gave me a new idea to learn...and served my purposes...

Comment: @Cthar - you should pick the answer that fits your question the best (also taking into account how well written and easy to understand it is) and accept it by clicking the tick adjacent to the question. You can give credit to other good answers by upvoting them. Of course positive comments are also welcome. Doing these things helps others to find the best answers and also rewards those that help you.

Comment: What I have done to maintain order is to prefix my items with a number ... for example, if I have 1000's of items, the first might be '0001 applesauce', then '0002 aardvarkberries' and then if I am using the actual entry name, I know I have to first remove '^\d{4}\s(.+)' and use $1 (assuming applesauce and aardvarkberries were two of my preferred hash keys). I acquired this idea from how Cisco maintains its EEM script ordering, and it has worked well for my purposes.

Comment: Actually, the above poster's idea sounds like another technique I've used - I reserve an assignment for the order of that hash entry. Then, though, I need to iterate through the hash repeatedly to populate an ordered list which I then reference to the key itself. That maintenance of a list of key names has other uses as well, such as when you are reading in a JSON-ish input file and want to populate hashes in the same depth as the input file (you would have a dynamic-depth of push'ed/pop'ed depth based on the indicators, say brackets in hashes, telling you when to perform which operation).

Answer (score 38):

Hashes are not ordered, but as usual, CPAN offers a solution: [Tie::IxHash](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tie-IxHash)

```
use Tie::IxHash;
my %count;
tie %count, 'Tie::IxHash';

while ($line = <DATA>) {
$count{$line}++ if ( $line =~ /\S/ );
}

while( my( $key, $value)= each %count) {
    print "$key\t $value"; 
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Data in a hash table is stored in order of the keys' hash code, which for most purposes is like a random order. You also want to store the order of the first appearance of each key. Here's one way to approach this problem:

```
my (%count, $line, @display_order);
while ($line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;           # strip the \n off the end of $line
    if ($line =~ /\S/) {
        if ($count{$line}++ == 0) {
            # this is the first time we have seen the key "$line"
            push @display_order, $line;
        }
    }
}

# now @display_order holds the keys of %count, in the order of first appearance
foreach my $key (@display_order)
{
    print "$key\t $count{$key}\n";
}
```

Comment: IMHO this is a better solution than using Tie::IxHash, which I think is beyond the OP's original needs. It is more suitable to use the display order of the keys, as in this answer, or to use `foreach my $key (sort keys %count) { ... }`

Answer (score 11):

From [perlfaq4](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4)'s answer to ["How can I make my hash remember the order I put elements into it?"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4#How-can-I-make-my-hash-remember-the-order-I-put-elements-into-it?)

---

How can I make my hash remember the order I put elements into it?

Use the Tie::IxHash from CPAN.

```
use Tie::IxHash;

tie my %myhash, 'Tie::IxHash';

for (my $i=0; $i<20; $i++) {
    $myhash{$i} = 2*$i;
    }

my @keys = keys %myhash;
# @keys = (0,1,2,3,...)
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply:

```
my (%count, @order);
while(<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  push @order, $_ unless $count{$_}++;
}
print "$_ $count{$_}\n" for @order;
__DATA__
a
b
e
a
c
d
a
c
d
b
```

Or as oneliner

```
perl -nlE'$c{$_}++or$o[@o]=$_}{say"$_ $c{$_}"for@o'<<<$'a\nb\ne\na\nc\nd\na\nc\nd\nb'
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option is David Golden's (@xdg) simple pure perl [`Hash::Ordered`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Ordered) module.  You gain order but it is slower since the hash becomes an object behind the scenes and you use methods for accessing and modifying hash elements.

There are probably benchmarks that can quantify just how much slower the module is than regular hashes but it's a cool way to work with key/value data structures in small scripts and fast enough for me in that sort of application. The documentation mentions several other approaches to ordering a hash as well.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not convinced that this is always a better technique, but I have used it sometimes. Instead of just having the "seen" type of hash, it can store both the count and order noticed.

Basically, instead of `$count{$line}` having the number of times seen, `$count{$line}{count}` is the times seen and `$count{$line}{order}` is the order in which it was seen.

```perl
my %count;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /\S/) {
        $count{$line} ||= { order => scalar(keys(%count)) };
        $count{$line}{count}++;
    }
}

for my $line (sort { $count{$a}{order} <=> $count{$b}{order} } keys %count ) {
    print "$line $count{$line}{count}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hashes are just arrays until they're assigned in Perl, so if you cast it as an array, you can iterate over it in its original order:

```
my @array = ( z => 6,
              a => 8,
              b => 4 );

for (my $i=0; $ar[$i]; ++$i) {
    next if $i % 2;
    my $key = $ar[$i];
    my $val = $ar[$i+1];

    say "$key: $val"; # in original order
}
```

You lose the benefits of hash indexing if you do that obviously. But since a hash is just an array, you can create one just by assigning the array to a hash:

```
my %hash = @array;
say $hash{z};
```

This is maybe just a variation on the "use an array as an index" solution, but I think it's neater because instead of typing out your index manually (or in some other way), you're creating it directly from the source array.