# Alphanumeric or natural sorting of keys in a hash

Tags: perl, sorting, data-structures, hash, perl-data-structures

I have keys in a hash as follows: `AB3, AB1, AB2` and so on.  I would like to sort the hash by the keys.  How do I do this in perl?

A related issue is how can I sort the keys so that letters and numbers appear in the correct order?

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question...

Answer (score 4):

You need the `sort` function:

```
foreach my $key ( sort keys %hash ) {
    print "$key => $hash{$key}\n"; 
}
```

You can't easily maintain hashes as sorted structures, as they just don't work that way. See: [`perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) for more about how hashes work.

Edit: One of the niceties of `sort` in perl though, is that it lets you specify a function. This function should take `$a` and `$b` and return `-1`, `0`, `+1` depending on if they're before or after.

`cmp` does that for alphabetical. `<=>` does that numerically. And best of all, when combined with `||` you can daisy chain the criteria, because `-1` or `1` are 'true' but `0` is false.

Something like this for example (borrowed the key list from another post to illustrate):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @keys = qw/ AB3 AB1 AB4
    CD5 CD107 CB8
    AC1 AC5 AC33
    BA84 CB11 CA233/;


sub lex_num {
    #split the keys into "word" and "digit" elements. 
    my @a_keys = $a =~ m/([A-Z]+)(\d+)/i;
    my @b_keys = $b =~ m/([A-Z]+)(\d+)/i;

    return ( $a_keys[0] cmp $b_keys[0] 
          || $a_keys[1] <=> $b_keys[1] );
}

print join( "\n", sort lex_num @keys );
```

This will sort the first bit lexically, the second bit numerically. If you've more combinations of letters and numbers then this won't work, but you can do e.g. a `split` and a `for` loop.

Comment: Yours is the canonical answer :-) (closest to the one from from the FAQ) I tried combining the basics with the sorting order issue raised by @Toto using a module.  Sobrique and Toto: Is there a shorter ""idiom" that would do natural sorting or is using a module defensible until one groks the code in Toto's response?

Comment: What do you mean by natural sorting? If I've a dual-key type sort (like numbers/letters) then usually I'll just do a regex to capture the two different values.

Comment: OK so more or less do as @Toto has done?  As I read it, `Sort::Naturally` is more or less hiding the block you can pass to the `sort()` function inside a module and providing a convenience function to wrap things up nicely.

Comment: Pretty much. Added my own illustration using the longer key list.

Comment: That's a bit nicer looking than @Toto ;-)  I knew there was a way `||` could shorten things.  In any case it is nice to know what goes on behind the scenes with something like `Sort::Naturally`. Cheers.

Comment: Modules are generally beneficial, but I find it really does help to understand what's actually going on behind the scenes - I assume `Sort::Naturally` does something a bit more comprehensive than in the above, but this is sufficient given the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

If your keys are defined by non digits followed by digits, you could do:

```
my %h = (
  CD45 => 4,
  AB1 => 1,
  AB22 => 3,
  AB5 => 2,
);
sub mySort {
  my ($xa,$ya) = $a =~ /^(\D+)(\d+)$/;
  my ($xb,$yb) = $b =~ /^(\D+)(\d+)$/;
  return -1 if $xa lt $xb;
  return +1 if $xa gt $xb;
  return $ya <=> $yb;
}
for (sort { mySort } keys %h) {
  say "$_ => $h{$_}";
}
```

**Output:**

```
AB1 => 1
AB5 => 2
AB22 => 3
CD45 => 4
```

Comment: Good answer to what is often the difficult part of a sorting operation. Unfortunately we have to guess at what problem the original poster is trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you might combine the two approaches and shorten your code by using a CPAN module - in this case [`Sort::Naturally`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Naturally) (I have made the hash keys a bit more complex for illustrative purposes):

```
use Sort::Naturally ;

my @keys = qw/ AB3 AB1 AB4 
               CD5 CD107 CB8 
               AC1 AC5 AC33 
               BA84 CB11 CA233/ ;

# make a hash from the keys with "whatever" as value:
my %hash;
%hash = map { $_ => $hash{$_} = 'whatever' } @keys ; 

# Auto-magically naturally sort alphanumerically
# A module based approach to @Toto's solution:
for ( nsort keys %hash ) { print "$_ => $hash{$_} \n" };
```

[@Sobrique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2566198/sobrique) has responded with the basic perl approach to sorting a hash by its keys, and [@Toto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372239/toto) has shown how you can sort those keys in a specified order using your own subroutine as an argument in the block `{ }` following the builtin `sort()` function.

**References**:

- The Perl Data Structures Cookbook (see `perldoc`[`perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html))
- The [Perl FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-sort-a-hash-%28optionally-by-value-instead-of-key%29?) on sorting hashes
- [How can I maintain the order of keys I add to a Perl hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558625/how-can-i-maintain-the-order-of-keys-i-add-to-a-perl-hash)
- [Why do hash keys have different order when printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340027/why-do-hash-keys-have-different-order-when-printing/30340150#30340150)

Comment: Removed the hash slice 5.20-ism:  `$_ = "whatever" for %hash{@keys};`